# Why is TCP limited to a 60-byte header?

Tags: tcp

From 《TCP/IP Illustrated, Volume 1 The Protocols》 17.TCP: Transmission Control Protocol

> The header length gives the length of the header in 32-bit words. This
>   is required because the length of the options field is variable. With
>   a 4-bit field, TCP is limited to a 60-byte header. Without options,
>   however, the normal size is 20 bytes.

Why is TCP limited to a 60-byte hader?

In my opinion

1) The header length gives the length of the header in 32-bit words. 32-bit means 4-byte.

2) 4-bit field can get 16 (2^4).

then 4 * 16, we get 64 not 60-byte. 
Am I wrong?

Comment: I would *guess* that to make processing as simple as possible, no fancy encoding tricks are used. The highest number that can be stored is 15, not 16, and 15*4 = 60. But by no means an expert.

Answer (score 2):

In [this TCP RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc761#section-3.1), the "data offset" portion specifies "The number of 32 bit words in the TCP Header." This part has 4 bits. Like @Damien_The_Unbeliever said, the highest number that can be stored in 4 bits is 15 not 16.

The highest number is 1111 = 2^0 + 2^1 + 2^2 + 2^3 = 15.

15 * 32 bits = 480 bits maximum in TCP header

480 bits / 8 = 60 bytes maximum in TCP header